# Unable to use the SendGrid to trigger the email for changes in blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid, azure-functions-runtime

I am new to MS functions and trying to create a C# function for triggering email when a new file is added in the Azure Blob storage.

Code sample below :

```
#r "SendGrid"
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;


public static void Run(string myBlob, string filename, ILogger log, out Mail message)
{
    var email = Regex.Match(myBlob, @"^email\:\ (.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value;
    log.LogInformation($"Got order from {email}\n License File Name: {filename} ");

    message = new Mail();
    var personalization = new Personalization();
    personalization.AddTo(new Email(email));
    message.AddPersonalization(personalization);

    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myBlob);
    attach.Content = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    attach.Type = "text/plain";
    attach.Filename = "license.lic";
    attach.Disposition = "attachment";
    attach.ContentId = "License File";
    message.AddAttachment(attach);

    var msgContent = new Content("text/html", "Your license file attached");
    message.AddContent(msgContent);
    message.Subject = "Thanks for your order";
    message.From = new Email("test3@test.com");  

}
```

I am running function version ~2 (checked the app setting variables).

**My question is why am I getting the error for Mail parameter (out Mail message )?**

SendGrid is installed correctly the last time I checked.

Following is the log which show compilation error: ( I have no idea why it is unable to recognize the Mail param in the method )

> 2018-11-26T05:46:57.013 [Error] run.csx(8,73): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name 'Mail' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did my solution work for you? Feel free to ask if you have met any problems.

Comment: I actually fixed my problem by creating a new Function app and selecting V1 of function run-time. The code worked as-is after that. Your answer seems correct for V2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mail` is the class used in v1 functions, which works with v8 SendGrid SDK. While for v2 functions, SDK is v9 and we use `SendGridMessage`, `Mail` is not available anymore so the error occurs.

If you are certain that Storage and SendGrid extensions are installed, have a try at code below.

```
#r "SendGrid"

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

public static void Run(string myBlob, string filename, ILogger log, out SendGridMessage message)
{  
    var email = Regex.Match(myBlob, @"^email\:\ (.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value;
    log.LogInformation($"Got order from {email}\n License File Name: {filename} ");

    message = new SendGridMessage();
    message.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));
    var base64Content = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myBlob));

    message.AddAttachment(
        "license.lic",
        base64Content,
        "text/plain",
        "attachment",
        "License File"
    );

    message.AddContent("text/html", "Your license file attached");
    message.Subject = "Thanks for your order";
    message.From = new EmailAddress("test3@test.com");
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "yourContainerName/{filename}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "message",
      "apiKey": "YOURSENDAPIKEYAPPSETTING",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```